# What's up with this C# code?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a split container which I need to be able to show and hide.

I tried "wiring" the split container to a button using the following code:

```
if (toolStripButton2.Checked == false)
{
    toolStripButton2.Checked = true;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = false;
    splitContainer1.Panel2.Show();                
}
if (toolStripButton2.Checked == true)
{
    toolStripButton2.Checked = false;
    splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = true;
    splitContainer1.Panel2.Hide();          
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I can't see any issue with the code. Maybe I'm overlooking something?

Any ideas?

--EDIT--

In order to get the contents of panel2 to display correctly, I need to maximize the form.

Comment: "But it doesn't seem to work.", can you tell more about this, and how to judge if it works?

Comment: Well, I ran the debugger and tried clicking the button and the split container panel 2 did not appear.

Comment: +1 for David. And add an `else` before your second `if`.

Comment: You can reduce this to `if (toolStripButton2.Checked) { ... } else { ... }`.

Comment: beside the problem you have (which you may want to describe if you wish help), you should use "else"...

Comment: What function is this code in?  If it is in the Checked Changed event of toolStripButton2 I can see why it doesn't work...

Comment: It _was_ on button click event, then I moved it to checked change event. Neither worked.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you have a logical error in your code.  If the `Checked` state is `False`, you then set it to `True`, which means your second `if` statement will be true, and the code will run in it.

Try using an `else` statement instead:

```
if (toolStripButton2.Checked == false)
{
    toolStripButton2.Checked = true;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = false;
    splitContainer1.Panel2.Show();
}
else 
{
    toolStripButton2.Checked = false;
    splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = true;
    splitContainer1.Panel2.Hide();
}
```

Comment: @Toby Are you sure your program *really* executes this part ?

Comment: No. I'm not. I'm new to this programming stuff, so to me this is all experience.

Comment: I would suggest you try placing a breakpoint on the first line of code, and then step through to follow the path of execution.  It may be that the code isn't being executed as you'd expect.

Comment: @Toby In cases like this you should place a *breakpoint* and *step* through the code line-by-line. Running debugger alone is not enough. Read here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn

Comment: I'll give it a look shortly.

Answer (score 5):

Where are you running this code? You probably want to catch the `CheckChanged` event on the button. Wire up a handler in your form `OnLoad`:

```
toolStripButton2.CheckChanged += toolStripButton2_CheckChanged;
```

And place the following handler, which will be executed after the check is changed:

```
public void toolStripButton2_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (toolStripButton2.Checked)
    {
        splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = true;
        splitContainer1.Panel2.Hide();

    }
    else
    {
        splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = false;
        splitContainer1.Panel2.Show();
    }
}
```

Since this handler runs after check is changed, you don't need to manually set the check state! If you set the check state to `false` when it is `true` (or the other way around), you would effectively **UNDO** the change.

Comment: I think, although it isn't stated, that the button does not automatically check/uncheck when clicked and that's what he wants to do. If it's checked when he clicks it, `.Checked = false`, otherwise `.Checked = true` He would also have to use the `Click` event.

Comment: @kschieck good point, but if I recall correctly a `ToolStripButton` has the `CheckOnClick = true;` property that... well, explains itself.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be:

```
if (toolStripButton2.Checked == false)
{
        toolStripButton2.Checked = true;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = false;
        splitContainer1.Panel2.Show();

}
else //toolStripButton2.Checked == true
{
        toolStripButton2.Checked = false;
        splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = true;
        splitContainer1.Panel2.Hide();
}
```